# How to set a function as map or weakmap with following code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Want to know how to set a function with object as a map or a weakmap. And how to Identify whether to use map or weakmap.

```
function testCases() {
  let model = new JsModel({name: 'Harry', age: 20});
 
  
  // few methods
  console.log(model.get('name')) // 'Harry'
  console.log(model.get('age')) // 20
 
  // few other methods
  model.set('name', 'Bob');
 
  console.log(model.get('name')) // 'Bob'
 
  console.log(model.has('name')) // true
 
  model.unset('name');
  
  console.log(model.has('name')) // false
 
  const city = new JsModel(); // valid
   city.set('name', 'San Jose');
   city.set('population', 1000);
 
  console.log( city.get('name')) // San Jose
  console.log( city.get('population')) // 1000
  console.log(city.get('noProp')) // undefined
}
 
 
testCases();
```

I am new to Javascript so want to understand if the above code like how to get these console.logs work.

Comment: I made it work partially. It is combination of object definition, map object and prototypes.

Comment: Not sure how your code works ... since `JsModel` is not defined

Comment: Define the JsModel as an object function JsModel(name, age) {
  this.name = name
  this.age= age
  return this
}

Comment: why isn't that in the code you want help with then

Comment: See this question is from one of the coding wars. We got make the code work. If it is not defined, then we got to define it. It is not part of the questions they asked.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should show the question they asked - because your code has no chance of working as is

Answer (score 0):

I've written a lot of javascript and never used WeakMap. Here is how I'd write that code.

```js
function testCases() {
  const model = {name: 'Harry', age: 20};
  
  // few methods
  console.log(model.name) // 'Harry'
  console.log(model.age) // 20
 
  // few other methods
  model.name = 'Bob';
 
  console.log(model.name) // 'Bob'
 
  console.log(model.name !== undefined) // true
 
  delete model.name;
  
  console.log(model.name !== undefined) // false
 
  const city = {}; // valid
  city.name = 'San Jose';
  city.population = 1000;
 
  console.log(city.name) // San Jose
  console.log(city.population) // 1000
  console.log(city.noProp) // undefined
}

testCases();
```